# Error: Coming in react-navigation v3 with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Before Calling `createReduxContainer` please call `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` so that we know when to trigger your listener

I am trying to integrate react-navigation v3 with redux and this above problem is showing on my simulator

Comment: please ask your question clearly. describe more about the problem...

Comment: How to resolve this error

Comment: I am trying to integrate react-navigation v3 with redux and this above problem is showing on my simulator @Naeim Fard

Comment: Adding some code will help us in helping you.

Comment: I've done this before. I'll send a tested sample for you

Answer (score 0):

This is a tested sample of react-navigation(v3) and Redux. Here the react-navigation is integrated into Redux. However, I declined to use this method anymore. I believe integrating is not necessary when it is going to make things more complicated.

App.JS file :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import {
  reduxifyNavigator,
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
  createNavigationReducer
} from "react-navigation-redux-helpers";
import MainScreen from "./Screens/MainScreen";
import SignUpScreen from "./Screens/SignUpScreen";
import rootReducer from "./src/rootReducer";
import ReduxNavigation from "./src/ReduxNavigation";
import { Directions } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    // LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
    MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
    SignUpScreen: { screen: SignUpScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "SignUpScreen"
  } 
  );

  const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(AppNavigator);
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer,
  app: rootReducer
});
const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  "root",
  state => state.nav
);
export const AppNav = reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigator, "root");
const store = createStore(appReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));


type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {


  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }



}
```

ReduxNavigation.js :

```
import React from "react";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

import { AppNav } from "../App";

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }

  onBackPress = () => {
    const { nav, dispatch } = this.props;
    if (nav.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    const { nav, dispatch } = this.props;

    return <AppNav state={nav} dispatch={dispatch} />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation);
```

- this code also support back button feature for Android devices.

Comment: Please use react-navigation ^3.6.1 and then make the example . Bcoz still it is showing same if we use 3.6.1 react-navigation version